# Error given in where a.Field<int>("ref_id") != b.Field<int>("ref_id") this line cause of b is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I want to get data like this but it gives me an error on where clause how
do write this query in Linq

```
var q = (from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
         join b in dt2.AsEnumerable() on a.Field<string>("id") equals b.Field<string>("id")
         into y
         from z in y.DefaultIfEmpty()
         where a.Field<int>("ref_id") != b.Field<int>("ref_id")
         select new wrongreferralDTO(){
                c_id = a.Field<int>("captain_id"),
                event_time = a.Field<DateTime>("event_time")
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Post the error and your models, we can't guess. By the way, don't cast a dbset to enumerable, it loads all records in-memory.

Comment: != b.Field<int>("referral_id")

Comment: difne? You mean defined?

Comment: Could "LINQ - Conversion in Where clause fails" be a clearer title? Besides doing what @MBakardzhiev said...

Comment: the  name "b" does not exist in currnt context

Comment: yes it makes sense. you never use z, why do you declare it?

Comment: cause of left join

Comment: 'cause of the `into y` you are converting it into a groupjoin (which is required to make a left join) but because of that you are losing the scope of `b` Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause to get more info about it

Comment: can you please try out updated answer ..

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this ,

```
  var refIdsToremove = dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(b => b.Field<int>("ref_id")).ToList();
            var q = (from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     join b in dt2.AsEnumerable() on a.Field<string>("id") equals b.Field<string>("id")
                     into y
                     from z in y.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where !refIdsToremove.Contains( a.Field<int>("ref_id") )
                     select new
                     {
                         c_id = z.Field<int>("captain_id"),
                         event_time = z.Field<DateTime>("event_time")
                     }).ToList();
```

as you cannot get access to b after putting join in other variable y, when you do `into y` b variable go out of scope